# How to do indentation of nesting of Associations, Lists and other heads?

Tags: boxes

I was looking at the presentation about [Wolfram's Symbolic ERP Project](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=2433) and in this video, they had functions to do nice indentation of nested `Associations`, `List` and other `Heads`. Is there an easy way to implement this or is there a hidden functionality in some undocumented context to do this?

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Example 3:

[image]

Example 4:

[image]

Example 5:

[image]